# List of S3 buckets and its lifecycle policies in .csv

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

```
def main():
    with open('S3.csv', 'w') as csvfile:
        writer = csv.writer(csvfile)
        writer.writerow([
            'Account Name',
            'Region',
            'Bucket Name',
            'Policy'

        ])
        with open('role.json') as ec2_file:
            ec2_data = json.load(ec2_file)
        region_list = ['eu-west-1']
        for region in region_list:
            for index in range(len(ec2_data['Items'])):
                Account_Number = ec2_data['Items'][index]['Aws_Account_Number']
                Account_Name = ec2_data['Items'][index]['Acc_Name']
                ARN = ec2_data['Items'][index]['ARN']
                b = get_assume_arn_to_keys(Account_Number,Account_Name,ARN)
                ds_client = boto3.client('s3',region_name=region,aws_access_key_id=``,aws_secret_access_key=``,aws_session_token=``)


                s3 = boto3.resource('s3')

                for bucket in s3.buckets.all():
                    writer.writerow([
                        Account_Name,
                        region,
                        bucket.name,
                        ds_client.get_bucket_lifecycle(Bucket=bucket.name)

main()
```

I wanted to list s3 buckets and its lifecycle policies in .csv. I can list all buckets.

But, listing lifecycle polices gives me the problem. I am not able to list for all buckets. Probably, It just gives me the first bucket's policy.

I am able to get the lifecycle policies, if I give the bucket name in line.
The single bucket 'k' policies are listed in all buckets.

```
ds_client.get_bucket_lifecycle(Bucket='k')
```

But, If I wanted to get for all buckets, I tried this

```
ds_client.get_bucket_lifecycle(Bucket=bucket.name)
```

Edit:::
New try to list logging, region and versioning.

```
import boto3
s3_client = boto3.client('s3')

bucket_list = ds_client.list_buckets()

for bucket in bucket_list['Buckets']:
    try:
        lifecycle = ds_client.get_bucket_lifecycle(Bucket=bucket['Name'])
        rules = lifecycle['Rules']
    except:
        rules = 'No Policy'                 
    versioning = ds_client.get_bucket_versioning(Bucket=bucket['Name'])
    logging = ds_client.get_bucket_logging(Bucket=bucket['Name'])
    print(bucket['Name'], rules, versioning, logging)
```

But couldn't get it. 
Kindly advice.
Thanks

Comment: "But, listing lifecycle polices gives me error." Could you please mention the error you are getting ?

Comment: @ArunNalla But, listing lifecycle polices gives me the problem. I am not able to list for all buckets. Probably, It just gives me the first bucket's policy.

Comment: Sorry I don't think I understood the question correctly. Are you getting any exception/error when you run this or is the problem that all the lifecycle policies are the same in the output file?

Comment: @ArunNalla If I am giving the bucket name directly, it gets me the lifecycle policy correctly. 

If I give (Bucket=bucket.name), it's NOT listing the bucket policies of all bucket(lists only for the first bucket). No specific errors.

Comment: It appears that, if a bucket does not have a Lifecycle configuration, a call to `get_bucket_lifecycle()` or `get_bucket_lifecycle_configuration()` will result in an Error. Are you sure the bucket in question has a lifecycle attached?

Comment: @JohnRotenstein You are correct. But, here I have a list of buckets and few doesn't have lifecycle policy and few have it.. 
My ultimate goal is get the lifecyle policy if it has, if not it should say 'no policy' or something. 

Please note, I am exporting in .csv and the lifecycle policies should be listed for all buckets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Trying to retrieve a lifecycle policy against a bucket that does *not* have a policy will result in an Exception.

Therefore, you will need to use a `try/except` like this:

```py
import boto3

s3 = boto3.resource('s3')

for bucket in s3.buckets.all():
    try:
        rules = bucket.Lifecycle().rules
    except:
        rules = 'No Policy'
    print(bucket.name, rules)
```

Or a client version:

```py
import boto3

s3_client = boto3.client('s3')

bucket_list = s3_client.list_buckets()

for bucket in bucket_list['Buckets']:

    try:
        lifecycle = s3_client.get_bucket_lifecycle(Bucket=bucket['Name'])
        rules = lifecycle['Rules']
    except:
        rules = 'No Policy'
    print(bucket['Name'], rules)
```

Comment: Is there a way that I could do it with s3 = boto3.client('s3').  Using client and not resource. Thanks

Comment: I've added a client version.

Comment: Thats great. Thanks.. I am also trying to get the properties like bucket logging, versioning etc details.. I edited the code in the initial post. please check. But gives me some metadata and not the expected data. please suggest.

Comment: You can ignore the metadata. The fields you want are listed in the boto3 documentation. For versioning, you want to see whether there is a `Status` field defined. For logging, you want to see whether `LoggingEnabled` is provided. I recommend you run your code against a bucket that does, and a bucket that does _not_, have the attribute (logging, versioning) enabled and take a look at the difference in the response sent back. You might need to use something like: `if 'Status' in response:`

Comment: This is what I get.....{'ResponseMetadata': {'RequestId': '6EA0C4BD25AB399B', 'HostId': 'bRA0gV6lgzvVD7WGVxZ0I0s95hzTN6uIsPMQ50D0xmTHDox9+ibl+k6asFxQkild6tZytW+fJ7Q=', 'HTTPStatusCode': 200, 'HTTPHeaders': {'x-amz-id-2': 'bRA0gV6lgzvVD7WGVxZ0I0s95hzTN6uIsPMQ50D0xmTHDox9+ibl+k6asFxQkild6tZytW+fJ7Q=', 'x-amz-request-id': '6EA0C4BD25AB399B', 'date': 'Fri, 07 Feb 2020 05:17:43 GMT', 'content-type': 'application/xml', 'content-length': '289', 'server': 'AmazonS3'}, 'RetryAttempts': 1}}

Comment: Yes, that is correct. That looks like a response for a bucket that does _not_ have logging/versioning. Do it for a bucket with logging/versioning enabled and you will see the difference in the response.